# Android: onclick not working

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

I'm doing in my app a ImageAdapter and i want that click on the image below the textview is hidden. But setInvisibility not work. El problem is nothing works with info. Is there a problem with views ... I need help please

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<imagenes.TouchImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textoInfoImagen"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/grisTransparente"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textColor="@color/gris"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**JAVA**

```
public class FullScreenImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements OnClickListener {

private Activity _activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;

String[] listaImagenes;
String monumento;

TouchImageView imgDisplay;
TextView info;

boolean invisible = false;

public FullScreenImageAdapter(Activity activity, Context context, String monumento) throws IOException {
    this._activity = activity;
    this.context = context;
    this.monumento = monumento;
    listaImagenes = context.getAssets().list(this.monumento);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listaImagenes.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ampliar_imagen, container,
            false);

    imgDisplay = (TouchImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
    imgDisplay.setMaxZoom(4);

    Bitmap bitmap = cargarImagen(monumento, position);
    imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    info = (TextView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.textoInfoImagen);
    info.setText((position + 1) + " de " + listaImagenes.length +
            "\n" + InfoImagenes.devolverInfoImagenes(monumento, position));

    imgDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(invisible == true) {
                invisible = false;
                info.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                invisible = true;
                info.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);

    return viewLayout;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

}

public Bitmap cargarImagen(String monumento, int position) {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream is;

    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

            is = context.getAssets().open(monumento + "/" + listaImagenes[position]);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    return bitmap;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
}

}
```

Comment: where do you set click listener?

Comment: set onclick in xml so that u can go to onClick method in ur code

Comment: the problem is onclick not working

Answer (score 0):

`info` is a member variable of your adapter and isn't necessarily the same view that was clicked - you overwrite the variable for each item.

`onClick()` comes with the `View v` argument which is the view that was clicked - call `setVisibility()` on it.

Also, `invisible` is a member variable with the same problems as above. Call `v.getVisibility()` if you want to examine the current visility of your view.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ImageView`'s (imgDisplay) type in **.java** class as `ImageView` instead of `TouchImageView`