# Android: Google Maps error

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

Hi I am having problems trying to put google maps on my second activity. It is a fragment. I have searched many related posts but I have not managed to fix my mistake ... I have the mistake to try to make the inflate. Thank you. This is my code:

**XML**

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" >

               <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/mapaTab"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

**JAVA**

```
public class DetalleMonumentoFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {  

public static final DetalleMonumentoFragment newInstance(String monumento){

    DetalleMonumentoFragment f = new DetalleMonumentoFragment();
    Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);

    bdl.putString("monumento", monumento);
    f.setArguments(bdl);
    return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    context = getActivity();

    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detalle_monumento_fragment, container, false); --> **MISTAKE**



    mapa = ((SupportMapFragment)   getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapaTab)).getMap();
    mapa.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    mapa.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 
    mapa.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

    cargarDatosMonumento();

    botonMapa = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonMaps);
     botonMapa .setOnClickListener(this);  
    return v;
}
```

**ERROR**

```
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #293: Error inflating class fragment
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at monumentos.DetalleMonumentoFragment.onCreateView(DetalleMonumentoFragment.java:172)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8335)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8335)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8335)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8335)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8335)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:843)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1892)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #293: Duplicate id 0x7f060040, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:296)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
02-25 11:42:48.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     ... 41 more
```

Comment: Follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin

Comment: Can you provide us the error message?

Comment: You either extend MapFragment or use MapView as shown in th elink posted in the first comment

Comment: @Raghunandan : u r awesome

Comment: thanks. my problem is solved. You could help me with the following problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985460/android-onclick-not-working

Answer (score 1):

I think you are working well but please you refer below link and go step to step.May be any step you will miss and you get error.

https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Maps-Fragment-Guide

I hope it will work for you.